# MongoDB aggregate count of items in array across different documents?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my MongoDB collection schema:

```
company: String
model: String
tags: [String]
```

I need to aggregate it so I get the following output:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "company": "Lenovo",
    "model": "T400"
  },
  "tags": {
    tag: "SomeTag"
    count: 124 // number of times, this tag was found in `Lenovo T400`
  }
}...]
```

I tried to do the following:

```
var aggParams = {};
aggParams.push({ $unwind: '$tags' });
aggParams.push({ $group: {
  _id: { company: '$company', model: '$model'  },
  tags: { $push:  { tag: '$tags', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
}});
```

But I got the following error:

```
invalid operator '$sum'
```

**What is the right way to do this with `aggregation`?**

Comment: Your data contradicts your schema. What is "tags" in your actual data? A string? Or an array?

Comment: `[String]` - represents an **array of strings**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to process [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on an array in order to deal with it meaninfully in aggregation. Also you adding to an array and "counts" stage a separate. As well an aggregation pipeline in an "array" of arguments itself, and not an object as you have defined:

```js
Model.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "company": "$company",
            "model": "$model",
            "tag": "$tags"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "company": "$_id.company",
            "model": "$_id.model",
         },
         "tags": { "$push": { "tag": "$_id.tag", "count": "$count" }
    }}
], function(err,result) {

})
```

So two [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages does the job here. One to sum up the tags within company and model and the other to group on just the "company" and "model" and add the distinct tags and counts to an array.