# MongoDB aggregate count of items in two arrays across different documents is the same?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my MongoDB collection schema:

```
company: String
model: String
cons: [String] // array of tags that were marked as "cons"
pros: [String] // array of tags that were marked as "pros"
```

Here is my `query`:

```
[
    { "$project": {
        "company": 1,
        "model": 1,
        "data": {
            "$setUnion": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$pros",
                    "as": "pro",
                    "in": {
                        "type": "$pro",
                        "value": "$$pro"
                    }
                }},
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$cons",
                    "as": "con",
                    "in": {
                        "type": "$con",
                        "value": "$$con"
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": { 
          "company": "$company",
          "model": "$model",
          "theTag": "$data.value"
      },
      "sumPros": { 
        "$sum": { 
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$data.type", "$pro" ] },
              1,
              0
          ]
        }
      },
      "sumCons": { 
        "$sum": { 
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$data.type", "$con" ] },
              1,
              0
          ]
        }
      }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "company": "$_id.company",
            "model": "$_id.model",
        },
        "tags": {$push: { 
          "tag": "$_id.theTag", 
          "pros": "$sumPros",
          "cons": "$sumCons"
        }

      }}
}]
```

Here is the output:

```
{
        "_id": {
            "company": "Lenovo",
            "model": "T400"
        },
        "tags": [
            {
                "tag": "Quality",
                "pros": 64, // expected value is 54
                "cons": 64  // expected value is 10
            },
            {
                "tag": "Value",
                "pros": 76, // expected value is 30
                "cons": 76  // expected value is 46
            }
        ]
}
...
```

**Notice that `pros` and `cons` values are the same. They, for some reason, represent the sum of `pros` and `cons` and I can't figure-out why.**

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Here is a document from the collection:

```
{
  "company": "Lenovo",
  "model": "X200",

  "cons": [
      "Quality"
  ],
  "pros": [
      "Value",
      "Styling"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It should not be. Can you expand on the question with a sample of data?

Comment: @BlakesSeven What data sample?

Comment: Well basically something people can cut and paste and use that confirms your results. I willl hapilly add here the "your query" is actually "my logic" gleaned from earlier questions here. But I have been working "blindfolded" so to speak because none of your questions present actual data to work from. The logic should be sound, but please show some base collection data that we all can try to work with.

Comment: @BlakesSeven This is a collection of reviews, which means there are a lot of documents with the same `model` name

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB aggregate count of items in two arrays across different documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155801/mongodb-aggregate-count-of-items-in-two-arrays-across-different-documents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the author of the content you are using in the query and also after asking you to submit some information in the form of data that actually supports the claim in the question here, I have to say that what you are saying is incorrect.

For the record, this is your sample at time of answer:

```
{
  "company": "Lenovo",
  "model": "X200",

  "cons": [
      "Quality"
  ],
  "pros": [
      "Value",
      "Styling"
  ]
}
```

On your sample here, if I run the following query ( and I do extend responsibity for any misleading operations in previous answers and will ammend those immediately ) then the results I see should be what is expected:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "company": 1,
        "model": 1,
        "data": {
            "$setUnion": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$cons",
                    "as": "con",
                    "in": {
                        "type": { "$literal": "con" },
                        "value": "$$con"
                    }
                }},
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$pros",
                    "as": "pro",
                    "in": {
                        "type": { "$literal": "pro" },
                        "value": "$$pro"
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "company": "$company",
            "model": "$model",
            "tag": "$data.value"
        },
        "pros": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$data.type", "pro" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "cons": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$data.type", "con" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Which produces from your sample

```
{
    "_id" : {
            "company" : "Lenovo",
            "model" : "X200",
            "tag" : "Quality"
    },
    "pros" : 0,
    "cons" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : {
            "company" : "Lenovo",
            "model" : "X200",
            "tag" : "Value"
    },
    "pros" : 1,
    "cons" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : {
            "company" : "Lenovo",
            "model" : "X200",
            "tag" : "Styling"
    },
    "pros" : 1,
    "cons" : 0
}
```

Which clearly correctly allocates both "pros" and "cons" totals across the grouping keys as should be expected.

Therefore what "I see" here is that the values are not in fact "the same" but are actually "different" as matches the different conditions given to each field accumulator.

---

Therefore taking that further, and based on your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32155090/5031275):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "company": 1,
        "model": 1,
        "data": {
            "$setUnion": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$cons",
                    "as": "con",
                    "in": {
                        "type": { "$literal": "con" },
                        "value": "$$con"
                    }
                }},
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$pros",
                    "as": "pro",
                    "in": {
                        "type": { "$literal": "pro" },
                        "value": "$$pro"
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "company": "$company",
            "model": "$model",
            "tag": "$data.value"
        },
        "pros": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$data.type", "pro" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "cons": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$data.type", "con" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "company": "$_id.company",
            "model": "$_id.model"
        },
        "data": { "$push": {
            "tag": "$_id.tag",
            "pros": "$pros",
            "cons": "$cons"
        }}
    }}
])
```

Produces:

```
{
    "_id" : {
            "company" : "Lenovo",
            "model" : "X200"
    },
    "data" : [
            {
                    "tag" : "Quality",
                    "pros" : 0,
                    "cons" : 1
            },
            {
                    "tag" : "Value",
                    "pros" : 1,
                    "cons" : 0
            },
            {
                    "tag" : "Styling",
                    "pros" : 1,
                    "cons" : 0
            }
    ]
}
```

Which is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: The problem with your solution, is that you have a list of **all tags of all models**, but what I need, is to have a list of **models** and have a `tags` property with the list of tags (like `tags: [{tag: "SomeTag", cons: 3, pros: 4}]`)

Comment: @MikeVayvala There is "no problem" here. All you need to do is apply the lesson from the [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32155090/5031275) you asked on this topic, and just add a second `$group` in order to `$push` the result content to an array. Do I need to repeat myself again?

Comment: if you look at my version of the query, you will see that I did `$push`, and now I have a completely different problem (described in the question )

Comment: and this answer is completely off-topic.

Comment: @MikeVayvala I really do not understand what you are banging on about. Your rudeness towards someone helping you is also unacceptable. See the edited details. "off topic" answer? No idea what you are even thinking there. Take a coffee break and do some reading/learning.

Comment: @MikeVayvala Wow. Dowvote and accept. Thats new. How about considering this was your problem and not mine?

Comment: @MikeVayvala your original answer was off topic, your edit however, answers my question. Thank you, and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @MikeVayvala Avoild asking further questions here iis my advice for you completely abhorrent behaviour here. You were helped in every respect.

Comment: People, why don't you make peace? Blakes Seven, you were obviously very helpful. Please edit your answer so that Mike can upvote it (currently he cannot). You will Mike, right?  And you, Mike can definitely use better language in your comments.

Comment: @kyrylkov Agreed completely. But with the extra information here that "Mike" is the judegmental downvoter here. Which is completely astounding given the level of help given. And also sorry if you think you are "making peace" here. But considering the question line, how unresearched would you consider the tone of the question?

Comment: @BlakesSeven Sorry that I downvoted you, but I can't upvote you, unless you make an edit to your answer.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Yes, I agree that downvoting was awfully inappropriate and I think that the question could have been researched better.